# apple simd Matrix Multiplication reversed in order?

Tags: c++, macos, matrix, graphics, simd

I have a extremely strange bug that I cannot really explain. I'm on MacOS using simd.h.
First a snippet from my program (don't mind the copies, they are on purpose to show the problem :) ):

```cpp
 auto p = scene.perspectiveCamera.projectionMatrix; // projectionMatrix is of type simd_float4x4
 auto v = scene.perspectiveCamera.viewMatrix; // viewMatrix is of type simd_float4x4
 auto m =  matrix_multiply(p,v);
```

I attached LLDB and have the following for variables `p` and `v` (which look as expected since this is a copy from my projection and view matrix):

```
 p simd_float4x4 = {...}
  columns simd_float4[4] = {(0.608465611, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), ...}
    [0] simd_float4 = (0.608465611, 0, 0, 0)
    [1] simd_float4 = (0, 1, 0, 0)
    [2] simd_float4 = (0, 0, 1.00002003, -0.0100002)
    [3] simd_float4 = (0, 0, 1, 0)
 v simd_float4x4 = {...}
  columns simd_float4[4] = {(-1, 0, 0, -0), (0, 1, 0, -0), (0, 0, -1, 7), ...}
    [0] simd_float4 = (-1, 0, 0, -0)
    [1] simd_float4 = (0, 1, 0, -0)
    [2] simd_float4 = (0, 0, -1, 7)
    [3] simd_float4 = (0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Now after the `matrix_multiply`, I would expect `m` to be well... the actual multiplication of `p*v` but what I get is `v*p` as the debugger suggest:

```
 m simd_float4x4 = {...}
  columns simd_float4[4] = {(-0.608465611, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), ...}
   [0] simd_float4 = (-0.608465611, 0, 0, 0)
   [1] simd_float4 = (0, 1, 0, 0)
   [2] simd_float4 = (0, 0, 5.99997997, 0.0100002)
   [3] simd_float4 = (0, 0, 1, 0)
```

for reference I would expect (the result of `p*v`):

```
 m simd_float4x4 = {...}
  columns simd_float4[4] = {(-0.608465611, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), ...}
   [0] simd_float4 = (-0.608465611, 0, 0, 0)
   [1] simd_float4 = (0, 1, 0, 0)
   [2] simd_float4 = (0, 0, -1, 6.99)
   [3] simd_float4 = (0, 0, -1, 7)
```

What to HELL is going on here?

I tried replicating this in a simple program that only does this matrix multiplication. However, this does not happen there (I get the actual correct multiplication), apparently only in my program. However, since I have my debugger output why is this an issue in my program???

**Solution:**
Thanks to @chtz: The matrices are store column major. Hence the initial multiplication is correct. I misassumed row-major storage.

Comment: Looks correct to me, assuming the matrices are stored column-major.

Comment: @chtz thank you kind sir! I went through my code and saw that I mixed up row and column wise matrix creation a few times... After changing it to column majors, I got my expected results.